# Calculadora científica con javascript - Realizar cálculos en un solo campo sin EVAL

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentado crear una calculadora científica en javascript, lo primero que estoy he intentado es hacer que todos los valores a operar se introduzcan en un mismo campo (*input,text*) y que muestre el resultado al hacer click en un botón, si tengo `2000 ÷ 110`  ó `200 x 5` en cualquiera de los dos casos dentro de un mismo input, he intentado que de alguna manera se ejecuten las operaciones y me regrese un resultado (estoy consciente que con **una función EVAL** las operaciones anteriores de esta forma `2000 / 110`  ó `200 * 5`, se ejecutarían pero no quiero hacerlo de esa forma). Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Este es el código que se tiene hasta ahora.

```css
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    
    
    
    
        .button1 {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            padding: 21px 34px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form name="calculat">
        <div style="padding-left: 10px;">
            <divstyle="padding-top:5px;padding-left: 10px;">
            <input type="text" class="numbers" name="numbers1" style="width: 325px;text-align: right;"></input>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top:5px;padding-left: 10px;">
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="7" onclick="numbers1.value += '7'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="8" onclick="numbers1.value += '8'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="9" onclick="numbers1.value += '9'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="÷" onclick="numbers1.value += '÷'"></input>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:5px;padding-left: 10px;">
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="4" onclick="numbers1.value += '4'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="5" onclick="numbers1.value += '5'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="6" onclick="numbers1.value += '6'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="x" onclick="numbers1.value += 'x'"></input>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:5px;padding-left: 10px;">
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="1" onclick="numbers1.value += '1'"/>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="2" onclick="numbers1.value += '2'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="3" onclick="numbers1.value += '3'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="-" onclick="numbers1.value += '-'"></input>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:5px;padding-left: 10px;">
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="0" onclick="numbers1.value += '0'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="." style="font-size:15px;" onclick="numbers1.value += '.'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="=" onclick="numbers1.value += '='"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="+" onclick="numbers1.value += '+'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="Del" onclick="numbers1.value = ''"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Brandon, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: Hola, podrías utilizar `split()`, para dividir la cadena por operadores aritméticos, vi que tu calculadora solo tiene "+-*/", vas a incluir otras funciones de calculadora científica (sin, cos, tan, ln, etc) ?

Comment: Efectivamente voy a implementar ese tipo de cálculos **the-breaker** puesto que si son necesarios

Comment: @BrandonEfrainLopezRamirez, podría ayudarte con la parte de operadores aritméticos, pero no se me ocurre como seria el funcionamiento de los otros operadores, depende cuales tienes pensado utilizar

Comment: @the-breaker agradecería mucho tu ayuda enserio te lo agradecería bastante, te comento que los demás operadores que usaría serian nada más, suma, resta, multiplicacion, división, elevar exponentes, y QUIZÁS si se puede % porcentajes

Comment: edita la pregunta para incluir el código en ella, por favor

Comment: Alguna vez hice una calculadora con un amigo (ArtEze), quizá te sirva como punto de inicio para tu desarrollo :) https://github.com/ArtEze/NaCludora

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este código genera una calculadora con los operadores básicos (+,-,x,÷), podría reducirse utilizando funciones dentro de la función.

```js
function evaluar(){
  cadena=document.getElementById('calc').value;
  
  division=cadena.split('÷');
  // alert(cadena);
  adiv=division[0];
  mult1=adiv.split("x");
  amult=1;
  for(i=0; i<mult1.length; i++){
    
    sumar=mult1[i].split('+');
    
    restar=sumar[0].split('-');
    res1=restar[0];
    // alert(res1);
    for(j=1; j<restar.length; j++){
      res1=res1-restar[j];
    }
    sum1=res1;
    for(j=1; j<sumar.length; j++){
        restar=sumar[j].split('-');
        res1=restar[0];
        for(k=1; k<restar.length; k++){
          res1=res1-restar[k];
        }
      sum1=sum1*1+res1*1;
    }
    amult=amult*sum1;
    // alert(amult);
  }
  // alert(amult);
  adiv=amult;
  for(i=1; i<division.length; i++){
    adivn=division[i];
    multn=adivn.split("x");
    sumar=multn[0].split('+');
    
    restar=sumar[0].split('-');
    res1=restar[0];
    // alert(res1);
    for(j=1; j<restar.length; j++){
      res1=res1-restar[j];
    }
    sumn=res1;
    for(h=1; h<sumar.length; h++){
        restar=sumar[h].split('-');
        res1=restar[0];
        for(k=1; k<restar.length; k++){
          res1=res1-restar[k];
        }
      sumn=sumn+res1*1;
    }
    adiv=adiv/sumn;
    for(j=1; j<multn.length; j++){
      
      sumar=multn[i].split('+');
      restar=sumar[0].split('-');
        res1=restar[0];
        // alert(res1);
        for(k=1; k<restar.length; k++){
          res1=res1-restar[k];
        }
        sumn=res1;
      
      for(h=1; h<sumar.length; h++){
          restar=sumar[h].split('-');
          res1=restar[0];
          for(k=1; k<restar.length; k++){
            res1=res1-restar[k];
          }
        sumn=sumn*1+res1*1;
      }
      adiv=adiv*sumn;
    }
    
  }
  document.getElementById('calc').value=adiv;
}
```

```css
       {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    
    
    
    
        .button1 {
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            padding: 21px 34px;
            text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form name="calculat">
        <div style="padding-left: 10px;">
            <divstyle="padding-top:5px;padding-left: 10px;">
            <input type="text" class="numbers" name="numbers1" style="width: 325px;text-align: right;" id="calc"></input>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-top:5px;padding-left: 10px;">
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="7" onclick="numbers1.value += '7'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="8" onclick="numbers1.value += '8'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="9" onclick="numbers1.value += '9'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="÷" onclick="numbers1.value += '÷'"></input>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:5px;padding-left: 10px;">
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="4" onclick="numbers1.value += '4'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="5" onclick="numbers1.value += '5'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="6" onclick="numbers1.value += '6'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="x" onclick="numbers1.value += 'x'"></input>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:5px;padding-left: 10px;">
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="1" onclick="numbers1.value += '1'"/>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="2" onclick="numbers1.value += '2'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="3" onclick="numbers1.value += '3'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="-" onclick="numbers1.value += '-'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="^" onclick="numbers1.value += '^'"></input>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-top:5px;padding-left: 10px;">
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="0" onclick="numbers1.value += '0'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="." style="font-size:15px;" onclick="numbers1.value += '.'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="="  onclick="evaluar()"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="+" onclick="numbers1.value += '+'"></input>
            <input type="button" class="button1" value="Del" onclick="numbers1.value = ''"/>
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

(*podría editarlo luego con otras funciones mas*)

Espero te sea de ayuda, saludos.

Comment: Waaaooo amigo enserio que esto me va servir mucho, enserio muchísimas gracias por tu ayuda, ya con esto creo que encuentro una manera de realizarlo, se te agrade, ha sido de mucha ayuda