# ¿como hacer operaciones aritméticas con un cadena?

Tags: javascript

Tengo las siguientes cadenas:

```
let str1 = "5 - 3 + 2 * 5"; // str1 = 20
let str2 = "123 / 3 + 4 * 0.5 - 55 + 1"; // str2 = -31,5
```

los operadores, los números y la cantidad de números pueden variar.

Necesito hacer operaciones aritméticas sobre ella con los operadores que le aparecen entre cada número y de izquierda a derecha.

Hasta ahora he intentado lo siguiente:

```
let arr1 = str1.split(' ');
let arr2 = str2.split(' ');

*arr1 = ["123", "/", "3", "+", "4", "*", "0.5", "-", "55", "+", "1"]*

*arr2 = ["5", "-", "3", "+", "2", "X", "5"]*

let tot = 0;
let _num = 0;
arr.forEach((e) => {
        if (tot==0) { 
            tot = Number(e);
        } else {
            if (e == '+' || e == '-' || e == 'X' || e == '/') {
                let sig = e;
            } else {
                _num = Number(e);
                if (sig=='+') {
                    tot += _num
                } else if (sig=='-') {
                    tot -= _num
                } else if (sig=='X') {
                    tot *= _num
                } else if (sig=='/') {
                    tot /= _num
                }
            };
        }
});
```

con el siguiente resultado

para arr1 , el total es tot = 150

para arr2, el total es tot = 186,5

porque hace las operaciones con el último operador en el arreglo.

Cuando el resultado debería ser el siguiente:

```
*arr1 = ["123", "/", "3", "+", "4", "*", "0.5", "-", "55", "+", "1"]*

127 / 3   = 41
41 + 4    = 45
45 * 0,5  = 22,5
22,5 - 55 = -32,5
-32,5 + 1 = -31,5
```

**tot = -31,5**

```
*arr2 = ["5", "-", "3", "+", "2", "X", "5"]*

5 - 3 = 2
2 + 2 = 4
4 * 5 = 20
```

**tot = 20**

*NOTA: Estoy aprendiendo a programar en javascript y se agradece que me saquen de este atolladero.*

Comment: Hola, te puede ser de ayuda esta pregunta [Calculadora científica con javascript - Realizar cálculos en un solo campo sin EVAL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/165083/calculadora-cient%c3%adfica-con-javascript-realizar-c%c3%a1lculos-en-un-solo-campo-sin-e/165136#165136)

Comment: Sin respetar el orden matematico?

Comment: el orden es de izquierda a derecha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo distinto a lo visto:

1. Defines tu Operaciones que hacen (funciones)
2. Asignas un objeto la operación que deseas hacer
3. Llamas a la función la operación que quieres hacer

Por ultimo para evitar buscar el primer valor lo asigno inicialmente con el calculo

```
 operaciones[arreglo[1]](arreglo[0],arreglo[2])
```

```js
let str1 = "5 - 3 + 2 * 5"; // str1 = 20
let str2 = "123 / 3 + 4 * 0.5 - 55 + 1"; // str2 = -31,5
let str3 ="8 * 2"
let str4 ="2 + 2"
function suma(a,b) {return a + b};
function rest(a,b) {return a - b};
function div(a,b)  {return a / b};
function mult(a,b) {return a * b};
const operaciones = {"+" : suma,
                     "-" : rest,
                     "/" : div,
                     "*"  :mult
                     
                 }
function calcular(str){
const arreglo = str.split(" ")
  valor_previo = Number(arreglo[0])
  for (let i = 1; i <arreglo.length; i = i + 2 ){
    valor_previo = operaciones[arreglo[i]](valor_previo,Number(arreglo[i+1]))
  
  }
  return valor_previo;

 


}
console.log("para str1", calcular(str1))
console.log("para str2", calcular(str2))
console.log("para str3", calcular(str3))
```

Lo que tal vez se un poco difícil de comprender es

```
const operaciones = {"+" : suma,
                     "-" : rest,
                     "/" : div,
                     "*"  :mult    
                 }
```

esto es un Objeto con la funciones previamente definidas, ejemplo para el "+" asigno la función suma

> Esta opción no toma en cuenta el orden matemático de la operación, el ejemplo de @Ruben si

Comment: Muy interesante tu código, tuve que verlo con determinación, pero tiene un detalle, cuando es una suma  simple, lo toma como un string, o sea '2' + '2' = '22' por todo lo demás muy bueno.

Comment: Si, olvide el cambio a number

Comment: La voy a evaluar como mejor respuesta, pero permíteme hacer  una pequeña mejora a tu código. 
    valor_previo = Number(arreglo[0])
    for (let i = 1; i <arreglo.length; i = i + 2 ){
      valor_previo = operaciones[arreglo[i]](valor_previo,Number(arreglo[i+1]))
    }

Answer (score 7):

En la cadena de entrada tienes `*` pero en el bucle estas chequeando por `X`:

```js
let str1 = "5 - 3 + 2 * 5"; // str1 = 20
let str2 = "123 / 3 + 4 * 0.5 - 55 + 1"; // str2 = -31,5

let arr1 = str1.split(' ');
let arr2 = str2.split(' ');

function result(arr) {
  let tot = 0;
  let _num = 0;
  let sig = '';
  arr.forEach((e) => {
          if (tot==0) { 
              tot = Number(e);
          } else {
              if (e == '+' || e == '-' || e == '*' || e == '/') {
                 sig = e;
              } else {
                  _num = Number(e);
                  if (sig=='+') {
                      tot += _num
                  } else if (sig=='-') {
                      tot -= _num
                  } else if (sig=='*') {
                      tot *= _num
                  } else if (sig=='/') {
                      tot /= _num
                  }
              };
          }
  });
  console.log(tot);
}
result(arr1);
result(arr2);
```

Comment: La pregunta tiene un problema conceptual, específicamente en relación a la precedencia de operadores.. El resultado correcto de la primer cadena es 12 y el de la segunda -11

Comment: Conozco el orden matematico de precedencia de operadores.  Sin embargo, cada problema y cada usuario tiene el derecho de especificar sus requerimientos.

Answer (score 5):

Seguramente la manera mas simple es mediante el uso de [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/eval)

```js
var str1 = '123 / 3 + 4 * 0.5 - 55 + 1'
console.log(eval(str1));
```

Como podrás ver en la página del enlace, se recomienda limitar el uso de `eval` pues dependiendo de cómo se use podría representar un riesgo. Si lo usas en código que sólo es accesible por tí, y lo utilizas con cuidado no deberías tener problemas.

Otra cosa a resaltar es el concepto [precedencia de operadores](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Operator_Precedence). Como verás el resultado de aplicar eval a la cadena `123 / 3 + 4 * 0.5 - 55 + 1` da como resultado `-11` en lugar de `-31,5` esto es porque primero se realizan las divisiones y multiplicaciones y luego las sumas y restas

```
123 / 3 = 41  
4 * 0.5 = 2

41 + 2 - 55 + 1 = -11
```

Para "forzar" el orden de izquierda a derecha, usa paréntesis.

```js
var str1 = '(123 / 3 + 4) * 0.5 - 55 + 1'
console.log(eval(str1));
```